# XNA How to make xna not to read transparent color

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I am fairly new to xna. I just created a sprite with transparent background(magenta). Problem is my Rectangle is reading the coordinates of whole sprite not of visible one. How do I make it read only the visible sprite.

```cs
myrectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, box.Width, box.Height);
```

I want to place my visible part not transparent at that position. Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no simple way, xna see sprite as image box no matter if is visible or not. you can adjust offset manually. why do you need that?

Comment: ok so if i have irregularly shaped person in that rectangular sprite how do i place that person in 0,0 position not the whole sprite?

Comment: pinckerman answer you. using surceRectangle in "spritebatch.Draw". this is used when you have one big image with all sprites (sprite sheet). and you manually must set sourceRectange coordinates to fetch that sprite. also will be good to set "origin", because default is on 0,0 coordinate so sprite will rotate around that corner.

Answer (score 6):

To transform a color to transparent, go to  the texture properties, content processor, and enable Color Key, and set the key Color to magenta.

[image]

Then to positioning the sprite where you want, you need to set the proper origin.

To set the ship center in the desired position, is needed to set the origin as shown:
[image]

So when you draw it, you need doing similar to this:

```
 var origin = new Vector2(40,40);
 spritebatch.Draw(shipTexture, shipPosition, null, Color, origin, ...)
```

You can change your texture rectangle source too:

```
 var texSource = new Rectangle( 25,25, 30,30);
 spritebatch.Draw(shipTexture, shipPosition, texSource, Color)
```

[image]

Although you may need to change the origin if you want to position the ship at its center

Comment: That's not what he is asking, changing that value results only in let XNA drawing the magenta background.

Comment: Changing that value results in NOT drawing the magenta background, and the topic is "How to make xna not to read transparent color", even so I have added the positioning part explanation...

Comment: Yes, but the point of his problem was "I want to place my visible part not transparent at that position", not the magenta transparency.

Comment: "How do I make it read only the visible sprite.", and he does not describe what position wants, it's a vague description that can be interpreted in several ways

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually measure the offset of the point you need using a program like Paint and then set that offset in the parameter `Origin` in the `Draw` method.
A better idea is to measure the size in pixel of your sprite (without the background) and the set it as the `sourceRectangle` in the `Draw` method.

```cs
spritebatch.Draw(textureToDraw, Position, sourceRectangle, Color.White)
```

`SourceRectangle` is nullable, its defalut value is `null`, and in that case XNA will draw the whole texture, and you don't need that.

Answer (score 1):

Using transparent color coding like Magenta is very old-fashioned. Nowadays we use the alpha in the images to achieve this.

I guess the only real way to do what you want to do is to search through the color-data to find the smallest and the largest x and y coordinates which have alpha > 0, or != Color.Magenta in your case.

```
Texture2D sprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>(.....);
int width = sprite.Width;
int height = sprite.Height;
Rectangle sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(int.Max, int.Max, 0, 0);
Color[] data = new Color[width*height];
sprite.GetData<Color>(data);
int maxX = 0;
int maxY = 0;

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {    
        int index = width * y + x;

        if (data[index] != Color.Magenta)
        {

            if (x < sourceRectangle.X)
                sourceRectangle.X = x;
            else if (x > maxX)
                maxX = x;

            if (y < sourceRectangle.Y)
                sourceRectangle.Y = y;
            else if (y > maxY)
                maxY = y;        
        }
    }
}

sourceRectangle.Width = maxX - sourceRectangle.X;
sourceRectangle.Height = maxY - sourceRectange.Y;
```

Comment: +1 for the introduction of the alpha channel, definitely something that needs to be explained more.

Answer (score 0):

I use a cheat method in VB.Net, which I assume you could make work in C#:

```
    Private Function MakeTexture(ByVal b As Bitmap) As Texture2D
        Using MemoryStream As New MemoryStream
            b.Save(MemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            Return Texture2D.FromStream(XNAGraphics.GraphicsDevice, MemoryStream)
        End Using
    End Function
```

As long as your bitmap is loaded with a transparent color, this works slick.