# C# How to detect collisions with other Texture2D's

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

```
if(drawRectangle.Right > drawRectangle0.Left)
{
   drawRectangle0.Y = 100;    
}
```

It's just a test to see if my code will detect it, and it does, but not the way I want to. See, when I don't even get near it, it moves anyway, I want it to, when it detects collision with `drawRectangle` (player `Rectangle`) to move, so the player can go and collect it again.

On another note, how do I get my `Texture2D`'s to appear without a white rectangle around them? How do I make that invisible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for overlapping between `Rectangle`s with `Rectangle.Intersects(drawRectangle, drawRectangle0);`

I think you are going to need to show a bit more code however, as it is hard to see the problem from that snippet.

What do you mean by a white rectangle around your textures? Do they have a white rectangle (non transparent?) when viewing in windows?

Answer (score 0):

If that "white rectangle" around your sprite is part of your original texture, you may need to tell XNA to don't draw that color and make it transparent. You have to change the *Color Key Color* from Magenta (255, 0, 255) to White (255, 255, 255) in the *Content Processor* properties, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18417841/2498113).

Usually it's better to use Magenta in your sprite as transparent color, as it's the default one in XNA. Or better, use a program like Photoshop or Paint.net and make it transparent using the alpha channel.

Comment: If there's something else that you don't understand, just ask :)